# All Cell properties null except ColumnId C# SDK

Tags: smartsheet-api

When retrieving a sheet via the C# SDK all the cell values are null.  Is there an access level for the API or does the C# SDK have a bug?  I can get the column names and id's fine.

```
SmartsheetClient ss = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(myToken).Build();
long sheet_ID = 0000000000000000;
Sheet sSheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheet_ID, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
lblFeedback.Text = "Sheet: " + sSheet.Name + " <br>Rows: " + sSheet.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

That works fine, so I know I'm accessing the sheet I want, so does the example column map from https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet/blob/master/csharp-read-write-sheet/Program.cs

However...

```
Cell completedCell = getCellByColumnName(r, "Completed", columnMap);
string cellValue = completedCell.DisplayValue;
```

cellValue is null.
Any cell property, except ColumnId comes back null.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What value is in your cell?

Suggestions:

- In the debugger, take a look at the row object and all the cells.
- Use a tool like Postman to make the call and examine the results

Comment: OK, so the column I'm looking for looks like this...
    {
    "id": 000000000000000,
    "index": 1,
    "title": "Completed",
    "type": "CHECKBOX",
    "validation": false,
    "width": 79
    }

So if a check box is unchecked it has a null value?  Not unchecked or false or 0?

Comment: If the cell has never been touched - then it's empty with no value. Otherwise value is true or false.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!